# Does the 'maximum' function for lists only work in a separate function?

Tags: list, haskell

I am having trouble understanding Haskell's error when I move the `Data.List maximum` function around different parts of my code. I'm using a few built-in functions to find the mode of an arbitrary list of integers. For example, when `mode` is given the list `list = [1,2,3,4,5,5,6,6,5,5,4,4,3,4,5,6,7,8,6,5,3,2,5]`, it should return `5`.

When I put the built-in `maximum` function inside of my `mode` function like so:

```
mode l = case l of
    [] -> []
    (x : xs) ->
        let x = map length (group (sort l))
            y = map head (group (sort l))
        in  snd (maximum (zip x y)) --<-----<-----<-- This Line
```

and I run `mode` on the above `list` with the command > `mode list` in `ghci`, it gives me the following error output:

```
<interactive>:2:7: error:
* Couldn't match type `Integer' with `[a]'
  Expected type: [[a]]
    Actual type: [Integer]
* In the first argument of mode', namely `list'
  In the expression: mode' list
  In an equation for `it': it = mode' list
* Relevant bindings include it :: [a] (bound at <interactive>:2:1)
```

However, when I split up the `mode` function into `mode` and `mode'` *(with `mode'` performing the maximum)* like so:

```
mode' f l = snd (maximum (f l)) --<-----<-----<-- Now Here

mode l = case l of
    [] -> []
    (x : xs) ->
        let x = map length (group (sort l))
            y = map head (group (sort l))
        in  zip x y
```

and I run `mode` on the above `list` with > `mode' mode list` in `ghci`, I get the expected output of `5` with no errors.

Can anyone explain why this is the case?

Comment: What is the expected type of `mode`? It would help if you added it to your code since the inferred type does not seem to be what you expect.

Comment: Why is the "mode" of a list of integers an empty list as in `[] -> []`?

Comment: You may be aware of this, but the error you are getting is a type error rather than a runtime error, i.e. it's the sort of error that is caught at compile time in normal compiled code. (new users are sometimes unclear about the difference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `mode' mode`, you can inline that to be:

```
mode l = case l of
    [] -> snd (maximum [])
    (x : xs) ->
        let x = map length (group (sort l))
            y = map head (group (sort l))
        in snd (maximum (zip x y))
```

Note that this is not the same thing as your original, because `mode'` is applied whether `list` is empty or not, where your original only applies it in the nonempty case.

Note also that `snd (maximum [])` typechecks but will throw a runtime error `Exception: Prelude.maximum: empty list`. This means that you still need to answer the question: what do I do for the empty list?

I think the answer must be that an empty list has no mode, so the thing you want to return must be a `Maybe`. That means you could use this definition:

```
mode l = case l of
    [] -> Nothing
    _ ->
        let x = map length (group (sort l))
            y = map head (group (sort l))
        in Just (snd (maximum (zip x y)))
```

(Note that I've replaced the unused `(x : xs)` pattern with `_` to avoid confusion when you define `x` again in the let.)

Comment: Your case model makes a lot more sense!

Comment: So I see my problem was that I was not consistent with my return types between cases. Suppose I wanted to return a number without the `Just` on the front of it. Is there some sort of a "null" number that could be returned instead of `Nothing` so I don't have to use `Maybe`?

Comment: btw you can also do your calculations in a single pass over `l`: `Just . snd . maximum . map (\xs -> (length xs, head xs)) . group . sort $ l`

Comment: "Is there some sort of a "null" number...?" No. `Maybe` exists because we **don't want** a null number. You have to be explicit in Haskell about the absence of a value. This is widely regarded as a feature, not [a bug](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare).

Comment: Of course, you are free to choose your own number to represent "null-ness", but then you wouldn't know the difference between the mode of an empty list and the mode of a list whose mode is that number.

Comment: `Maybe`s aren't that hard to deal with. They are `Functor`s, `Applicative`s and `Monad`s so it is easy to "get under" the `Just` to work on the value it contains in a safe way. With `maximumMay` from the 'safe' package, the whole thing can be written as: `mode = fmap snd . maximumMay . map (\xs -> (length xs, head xs)) . group . sort`, which is shorter than your original.

Answer (score 3):

Take a closer look at the `case` statement in `mode`:

In your working example:

```
mode l = case l of
    [] -> []
    (x : xs) -> let ... in zip x y
```

The return type of `mode` is a list. In the broken version:

```
mode l = case l of
    [] -> []
    (x : xs) -> let ... in snd (maximum (zip x y))
```

The return type in the first branch is a list, but in the 2nd branch it's an `Integer` (as `zip x y :: [(Integer, a)]`). That's a type error.

In the working case, the other branch of `mode` returns a list and so the type is valid: `mode :: (Num a, Ord b) => [b] -> [(a, b)]`, and `mode'` typechecks as well.

The error message `Couldn't match type 'Integer' with '[a]'` says that the function expected a list `[a]` but instead got an `Integer`: your list contains the integers, so you can tell that the function was expecting the argument to be a list of lists instead: then the type is valid (`mode :: Ord a => [[a]] -> [a]`).

Comment: Your solution provides a good explanation for why the broken version did not work (the type mismatch). I chose the other solution as the answer because is provided a better final version of the desired mode function (with the use of `Maybe`).